# Ember nested route not rendering template

Tags: templates, ember.js, routes, nested, request

I am using the latests ember-cli version 2.12.1 and ember.

I have configured my routes as this:

```
 Router.map(function() {
  this.route('companies', function() {
    this.route('companydetail', {
      path: '/:company_id'
    }, function() {
      this.route('employees', function() {
        this.route('employeedetail', {
          path: '/:employee_id'
        });
      });
    });
  });
});
```

The templates are in

```
/templates/companies/index.hbs
/templates/companies/companydetail.hbs
/templates/companies/companydetail/employees/employees/employeedetail.hbs
```

I can link to the route

```
{{#link-to "companies.companydetail.employees.employeedetail" model employee}}Edit{{/link-to}}
```

and that works. But the template is not rendered. 
    Instead the companydetail.hbs is used. I changed the 
 /routes/companies/companydetail/employees/employeedetail.js to render the correct template:

```
renderTemplate: function(params) {
    this.render('companies/companydetail/employees/employeedetail', {
      into: 'application'
    });
}
```

This is working, BUT: the call to the model (request to the server) is not done. I could try and make the call manually, but I start to believe, that I am doing something wrong with the route.

Any advice?

UPDATE:
The url is /companies/1/employees/2. When ember constructs this url when I click on a link, the request to the model is not executed. When I refresh the browser page, the requests are fired. This is a somewhat typical experience since the model-call is not triggered when the url not changed. But the strange thing is, that it changes and still no model-request...

Thanks in advance,
Silas

Comment: `/templates/companies/companydetail/employees/employees/employeedetail.hbs` this should be `/templates/companies/companydetail/employees/employeedetail.hbs`

Comment: @kumkanillam you are right. That's where the script is at. It was a typo here in the question. Sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That the `companydetail.hbs` is used is correct. The `employeedetail.hbs` should be rendered into the `{{outlet}}` inside the `companydetail.hbs`. Make sure to have an `{{outlet}}` inside the `companydetail.hbs`.

Comment: Hm. I want it to be rendered on a new page, not inside of the companydetail. I tried your solution but it didn't work.The strange thing is: when I reload the page, all requests are correct.

Comment: this is expected. If you `{{link-to}}` with a model the `model` hook is not executed, because you already have the model. And if you don't want your templates to be nested don't nest your routes.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! My code is working now: I changed the {{link-to}} from {{ ... model employee }} to {{ ... model.id employee.id}} This way not the model is passed but the id and the request is triggerd.